# Using individual css packages installed with npm in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel-5

I would like to take advantage of the benefits of npm for installing packages and using them in my views.

However I don't want to systematically compile them in a single file (`css/app.css` for example). I would like to be able call them individually as the following:

```
//Installation with npm:
npm install animate.css --save    

//In HTML, simply call the installed package
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

I know how to do it in a single file with webpack but on some page of my site I would just like to use a single package, not all the package merged in `css/app.css`.

**EDIT**: made the question clearer

Comment: You could try using the pre-compiled version (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css) in this specific case

Comment: Yes but it was just as an example.

Comment: In a more abstract sense you could parse the CSS files using something like [Rework CSS](https://github.com/reworkcss/css), then merge the separate CSS rules or inject @include tags into the rule set. - **Edit:** i will note the project looks abandoned currently.

Comment: After a quick google (see: https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/10/22/gulp-merge-less-sass-css/) for merging CSS with GULP